# possible memory leak when returning a string?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I use valgrind --leak-check=full check my program, and got a leak which I have no idea with:

```
==6072== 54 bytes in 2 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 15 of 28
==6072==    at 0x4C2AF8E: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6072==    by 0x55B63B8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==6072==    by 0x55B7D94: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==6072==    by 0x55B7E72: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==6072==    by 0x4268ED: Writable::readString(std::istream*) (Writable.cpp:33)
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
#include "Writable.h"

Writable::Writable()
{
    //ctor
}

Writable::~Writable()
{
    //dtor
}


void Writable::writeString(ostream* ofs, string str){
    int length = str.size()+1;

    ofs->write((char*)&length, sizeof(length));

    if (length > 1)
        ofs->write(str.c_str(), length);

}

string Writable::readString(istream* ifs) {
    int length = 0;

    ifs->read((char*)&length, sizeof(length));

    if(length > 1) {
        char buf[length];
        ifs->read(buf, length);

        return string(buf);
    }

    return string("");
}
```

It's pointing to the "return string(buf)" line. Can you figure out how the leak is done there?

Cheers

Comment: Variable-Length Arrays are not part of standard C++. Anyway, returning a `std::string` is fine, and you don't have to cast it when you do.

Comment: What do you get when returning a "plain" string?    `string Foo() { string bar = "Hello, World"; return bar; }`

Comment: `int length = 0; char buf[length];` how can you even compile?

Comment: Please shows us your real code.You cannot have arrays of length `0` in C++.

Comment: and length must be const integer

Comment: @billz: That might work assuming most compilers support VLA through compiler extesions.

Comment: thanks @AlokSave always something new for me to learn

Comment: There is no 0-length arrays in this code, `char buf[length]` is instantiated only if `length > 1`.

Comment: Hard to say, since I can't compile the sample. I *can* tell you that it works(more on that in a sec) when I replace your VLA with an std::vector<char> and size it appropriately. Note: the storage of your length as a platform-int is pinning you both to whatever your platform uses for an `int` *and* the endian-ness of said-same. If you have any hopes or desires of the data file+data-reader combo ever working on multiple platforms with varying `int` and endian configs, you should address this.

Comment: anyway in my testing, valgrind's report is quite clean

Comment: Is this comming from static storage duration object. As this may generate false poositives depending on when the valgrind libraries are interjected into the processes.

Comment: The length is not 0, it's read from ifs

Comment: @Loski : I think this is a false positive. When I fix another leak warning, this is gone :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am not really sure what you are trying to do here. For your `writeString` method (why should it be a method if it does not use any members?), you should pass the stream as reference, and your string as constant reference. Your code could be simplified to this:

```
void Writable::writeString(std::ostream & ofs, std::string const & str){
    ofs << str;
}
```

No need to fiddle with pointers and buffers yourself if the standard already does that for you.

As for your `readString` "method": It seems you try to read 4 characters (`sizeof(length)`) and store them in `length`. If you have 4 characters, say "abcd", your `length` variable contains the bit pattern `41424344` (hexadecimal). In decimal, this is `1094861636`. Basically, you then try to read the next billion characters from your stream (after the `abcd` you extracted earlier). It is quite likely that your stream does not contain one billion characters, so a good portion of your buffer will be left uninitialized. If you are lucky, you find a NULL character somewhere which terminates your stream.

I do not know if you want to read the entire stream or just a line. In the latter case, you could simplify your code to:

```
std::string Writable::readString(std::ostream & ofs){
    std::string extracted;
    getline(ofs, extracted);
    return std::move(extracted); // or return extracted; if you have a pre C++11 compiler
}
```

Hope this helps.